# windows service best practice

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

For some reason(e.g. I want it to run automatically at system start-up and last forever), I decide to develop my program as a windows service application. Currently, my implementation is as follows:

1. Implement the main business logic as a class library.
2. Implement a windows console application as client program which will construct the business object and periodically call the business logic component.
3. Develop the windows service application to start and stop the console application.

   3.1 Start the process in the OnStart method.

```cs
    djsProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                WorkingDirectory = rootDir + depolyDate,
                Arguments = args,
                FileName = rootDir + depolyDate + @"\" + appName                
        };
        try
        {
            djsProcessToRun = Process.Start(djsProcessStartInfo);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             ///
        }
```

3.2 Stop the process within OnStop method.

```cs
        if (djsProcessToRun != null)
        {
            try
            {
                djsProcessToRun.Kill();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ///...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ///...
        }
```

Is this the right way to develop the windows service application?
I happened to encounter the problem when the process djsProcessToRun failed to run or sometimes I cannot stop it. 
Is there any best practice there I should follow?(e.g. how to handle exception, how to separate the function between windows service and the target windows application)

Comment: why you make a console application? I suggest put business logic in Class library and within your Windows service write code to include those file and do the logic, this way you consume less resources as no seperate process is maintain.

Comment: I have updated my problem description, please review again.

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be to use a shared assembly (i.e. a class library) and then you can create two clients that use the shared assembly - your test console application, and your windows service.

Comment: I've updated the problem description. it's almost the same with your suggestion, except that the service call the console applicaiton rather than the class library directly. Because i want to keep the service as simple as possible and when i updated my business logic part, i do not want to change the service and re-install it.

Comment: When you recompile the service you don't have to reinstall it, just replace compiled EXEcutables, after stopping service will do. Plus you ask for Best practise, as I said in my above comment, this suggest take less resources and give more flexibility to error handling then console application.